# How to compute performance of a detection-classification system?

Tags: accuracy, performance

I use a yolo (y) to detect only one object and a multiclassifier (mc) that classifies that object.
Now, the problem is: what I have to do with yolo's false positive and false negative, if I want to compute the whole system accuracy, precision and recall?

Now I'm computing overall accuracy like this:

`acc = (tp_mc + tn_mc) / (tp_mc + tn_mc + fp_mc + fn_mc + fn_y + fp_y)`

To compute precision and recall I'm doing that for each class of mc:

`precision_i = tp_mc_i / (tp_mc_i + fp_mc_i + fp_y_i)`

`recall_i = tp_mc_i / (tp_mc_i + fn_mc_i + fn_y_i)`

Where fp_y_i and fn_y_i are the yolo's false positive and false negative that belongs to the class i of the multiclassifier.
Do you think that this is the correct way to compute accuracy, precision and recall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What matters is whether the instance is classified correctly or not at the end, so it's only about mapping correctly the cases from the `y` classifier:

- `tp_y` is easy, it's the classification status of the `mc` classifier
- `tn_y` is a TN for every class $i$.
- `fp_y` is a FP for the class $i$ predicted by `mc` and a TN for every other class.
- `fn_y` is a FN for the true class $i$ and a TN for every other class.

I'm not sure what you count as `tn_mc` here?  Normally in a multiclass setting accuracy is the sum of $TP_i$ for every class $i$, because there's no TN. That would give us:

$$acc=\frac{\sum_{i}TP_i}{n}$$

With $n$ the total number of instances (from the start, not only the ones fed to `mc`)

Your precision and recall formulas look correct to me, assuming that `fp_y_i` are the FP instances where $i$ is the *predicted* class whereas `fn_y_i` are the FN instances where $i$ is the *true* class.